# create custom registration form in laravel with

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to create registration form in laravel but with my custom input fields, I've changed the 'register.bladed.php' to change the 'view'.

The default registration form was containing `name` , `email` , `password`, `confirm Password`.

I added two new input fields i.e `gender` and `date-of-birth`.

I made changes to the `create_users_table.php` with above two new input fields and then migrate that which results into the following table structure.

[here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt95q.png)

Now when I try to `register` any user it gives me the following error

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'gender' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (abc, abc@gmail.com, $2y$10$wGLT0qsJ3EmSSa4vzTj0sOop6eRvtPShg9.aEZ6wJFJY8OdHMsrBO, 2019-06-07 15:55:08, 2019-06-07 15:55:08))

I think I want to change something where the form is submitting, but there are two `functions` where the form is submitting i.e route `register`

1.`validator`
2. `create`

I don't know what to do with that ?

What changes do I need to make to have the new input new input fields working, and in future which things should I do to make custom input fields working correctly .

The name for `date-of-birth`is `dob` given as:

```
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="dob" type="date" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required autocomplete="dob">

                            @error('dob')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
```

for `gender` it is :

```
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select id="" class=" form-control" name = 'gender' required>
                                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Fe Male">Fe Male</option>
                            </select>

                            @error('gender')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
```

I've used the same names in RegisterController.php.

the `table` looks like this :

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->date('dd/mm/yy')
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I've made some manual changes to the `table` in my `phpmyadmin` according to the above structure of the table, without `php artisan migrate`.

May be something that is obvious I'm asking about , but I'm new totally new to laravel.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford it, delete the old table and create a new one. Adapts the class for migrations. This way SQL will know what to allocate by default if it is not informed.
Try this.

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('gender')->default('Your default value');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: let me try that

Comment: should I store the date-of-birth as `string` or as date, because I don't know either `date()` function either exists or not ?

Comment: Me I use date() like this :
    $table->date('birth_date')->nullable();

Comment: Yes , you can use `date()` function like I've used , it will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

you should add the two fields within the 2 methods `validator` and `create` of `RegisterController` like below :

ps: please check the fields name within your form

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

  // some code ... 


 protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',

            'gender' => 'required',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required'
        ]);
    }


     protected function create(array $data)
        {
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['email'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

                'gender' => $data['gender'],
                'date_of_birth' =>  $data['date_of_birth'],
            ]);
        }
}
```

Comment: I made these changes, but it's giving the same error again

Comment: do you get checked the name of your new inputs as mine here within the tow methods?

Comment: Yes, and I've used `name = 'gender' ` on select element, hope that is not a problem, just confirming .

Comment: update your question and put your html form code please

Answer (score 1):

In your table the field "gender" is non-null, which means that when registering a new user you must give it a value. Which is not done, which is why you have the mistake. You can still set a default value in your Migration class or specify Null: YES as for "email_verified_at for example for "gender"
I hope that my explanations can help you.

Comment: But I'm giving a value to gender, but the query is not taking that , as I mentioned there is something wrong when the form is submitting and the gender is not being set for some reason

Comment: @mehmood did you not see my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the user model and add the name of the database column that corresponds to your custom fields in the fillable variable as follows:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
        /* Custom Fields*/'gender_id', 'city_id',/* Custom Fields*/
    ];
```